# Blue Screen Crash on Low Battery

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card, bsod, battery

Have been having this problem for a long while now, finally deciding to deal with it.

When my laptop goes into critical low battery mode, a BSOD pops up with `DXGKRNL`. This only happens when the laptop is on battery (not plugged in), so it seems unlikely that it is a hardware failure.

Find the .DMP here: https://pastebin.com/qPXDYKwB

Laptop: Helios 300, 16gb RAM, 1660ti,

What I've tried so far:

- Reinstalling NVidia drivers with DDU in safe mode
- Reinstalling Windows
- Resetting power management
- Updating BIOS

Please let me know any addition information I can provide that can help with troubleshooting this.

Comment: Set Power Management to Suspend (preferable) or Hibernate (less preferable) at 15% battery level. If the machine crashes at 15% move to 20% and let us know. Battery should be OK to down to 15% (even down to 10%) but not a lot less.

Comment: @John Thanks for the suggestions, still crashing at 20% for the critical level

Comment: Your battery may need replacing. I have seen this. Try a higher percentage until is does not crash. Since you reinstalled Windows and Drivers I am assuming this are fine.